# grab a value from dynamic SOAP response with xpath

Tags: xml, soap, xpath

I need to extract a value from a SOAP response using Xpath. Here is the SOAP Repsonse format:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
         <ns1:getServiceInfosResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ws.commande.lcm.somecompany.com/">
             <return xmlns:ns2="http://ws.commande.lcm.somecompany.com/">
                <customer>
                    <userid>12545646546</userid>
                    <servicesNumber>3</servicesNumber>
                    <service>
                        <serviceid>257</serviceid>
                        <state>activated</state>
                        <counterValue></counterValue>
                        <parametersNumber>0</parametersNumber>
                    </service>
                    <service>
                        <serviceid>692</serviceid>
                        <state>activated</state>
                        <counterValue></counterValue>
                        <parametersNumber>0</parametersNumber>
                    </service>
                    <service>
                        <serviceid>1077</serviceid>
                        <state>activated</state>
                        <counterValue>0</counterValue>
                        <parametersNumber>0</parametersNumber>
                    </service>
                </customer>
            </return>
        </ns1:getServiceInfosResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am tying to get the value of counterValue tag where serviceid is 1077. 
here's what I did, but it's not working :

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:getServiceInfosResponse/return/customer/service/serviceid[text()='1077']/counterValue
```

and this :

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:getServiceInfosResponse/return/customer/service[serviceid='1077']/counterValue
```

Here is a [link](http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=812fb3b7-1eb9-4270-87b1-a248b8daa947-xpath#.VCp16_l5OiR) for a live checker.

please check what's wrong

Comment: What language are you using - java, php, other?

Comment: @web-nomad: no language is envolved i am looking for the absolute path to grab the value in xpath in general

Comment: the 1st XPath is wrong because `counterValue` isn't child of `serviceid`. But the 2nd XPath should work, assuming namespace prefixes resolved properly

Comment: @har07: based on http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp both should work. could you please explain how namespace prefixes resolution could affect this (just want to undersand that, namespace in this case is correct).

Comment: the first one is wrong as @har07 said. If you change the latter part of the first xpath from `serviceid[text()='1077']/counterValue` to `serviceid[text()='1077']/following-sibling::counterValue`, it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sure the problem is with the namespaces in your SOAP file, like ns1, the best way is to ignore them
try this it works

```
  /soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/*/customer/service[serviceid='1077']/counterValue
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution, but this is not working, u can check it live at this link http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=812fb3b7-1eb9-4270-87b1-a248b8daa947-xpath#.VCp16_l5OiR

Comment: i have tested and sent the answer, its strange the answers are different 
http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: in fact, I tried this on the communicated website but it's not working, but when tried with this local app http://www.bubasoft.net/product/xpath-builder/ it works